# Roots of a quadratic function with complex coefficient

Tags: complex-analysis, quadratics

Consider the quadratic function
$$
x^2 + \alpha x +1 = 0
$$
where $\alpha = \gamma + \delta i$ for $\gamma, \delta \in [-100, 100]$.  It is claimed that for any root of the equation $\hat{x}$, we have
$$
|\hat{x}| \leq C \delta^{-1}
$$
for some universal constant $C$.  I'm not familiar with quadratic equations with complex coefficients, so I'd appreciate a hint or sketch of the solution.

Comment: You want to solve for $x$?

Comment: If we specialize to $\gamma = 0$ and take large $\delta$ then there is a root near $-\delta i$, which of course has large norm.

Comment: Sorry, added boundedness conditions on $\delta$ and $\gamma$

Answer (score 2):

The product of the two roots is $1$.  If both roots satisfied that inequality, we would have
$$ 1 \le C^2 \delta^{-2}$$
so $|C| \ge \delta$.  Thus there can't be such a constant.

EDIT: The roots (given by the usual quadratic formula) are continuous functions of $\alpha$, so if $\alpha$ is bounded the roots  are also bounded.

Comment: Sorry, added some conditions for $\delta$ and $\gamma$.  Both are bounded.

Answer (score 0):

You claim is equivalent to that if $\hat z=δ\hat x$ is a root of
$$
z^2+δ(γ+δi)z+δ^2=0
$$
then $\hat z$ is inside some bounded set. That is true if you bound $δ$ and $γ$ (by $100$), as a simple root bound gives that
$$
δ|\hat x|=|\hat z|\le \max(1,|δ(γ+δi)|+δ^2)\le C=(1+\sqrt2)100^2
$$

Comment: what is the root bound you speak of?

Comment: also it seems like the first term of your equation should be $\delta^2 z^2$

Comment: If $z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+..+a_1z+a_0=0$ then $$|z|\le\max(1,|a_{n-1}|+..+|a_1|+|a_0|),$$ I think it named "Lagrange bound". And no, $z^2=δ^2x^2$.